# How do you block in rust until a file has more data

Tags: windows, file, rust, io, eof

I am automatically reading a log file written by another application using [BufRead::read_line](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.read_line):

```
let file = File::open("foo.log")?;
let mut reader = BufReader::new(file);
let mut line = String::new();
loop {
    line.clear();
    let size = reader.read_line(&mut line)?;
    if size != 0 {
        // ... process line
    } else {
        // How do I block until reader is no longer at EOF?
    }
}
```

When I reach the end of the file I want to wait until more data is available.
Is there a better alternative than a busy wait with something like `sleep(Duration::from_millis(50));`?

I have already looked into the [notify](https://docs.rs/notify/4.0.17/notify/) crate to wait for [write](https://docs.rs/notify/4.0.17/notify/op/index.html#write) events, but it looks like on Windows those events only occur when the file is closed (even when using the raw API), but in my case the application keeps its log file open until it is shut down.

Using `async` would also be fine (even preferred).

Comment: For what it is worth, the GNU `tail -f` implementation uses `inotify` if available and then a loop with `sleep`. And AFAIK `inotifyp  is not available on Windows, so... here you are.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sketch of a pooling-based approach I worked out.  You could perhaps couple this with a read-only open of the file, seek to the last known size, then read in any changed data.  Obviously this is only a sketch of an approach.  And, it still uses a thread sleep.  But, I haven't found anything better to address the same question.  I'd love to know if you ever worked out a solution.

```
use std::{fs, thread, time};
use std::time::SystemTime;

fn main() {
    let pool_interval = 1; // seconds
    let path = "../path/logs/logfile.log".to_string();
    println!("watching {}", path);
    let mut last_modified:u64 = 0;
    loop {
        let attr = fs::metadata(&path).unwrap();
        let modified = attr.modified().unwrap().duration_since(SystemTime::UNIX_EPOCH).unwrap().as_secs();
        if modified != last_modified {
            last_modified = modified;
            let filesize = attr.len();
            println!("modified: {:?}, new size: {:?}", modified, filesize);
        }
        thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_secs(pool_interval))
    }
}
```

Comment: The solution we ended up using is a mixture of the notify crate and polling. We wait for a write event, but with a timeout. If no event occurs within the timeout we continue to read anyways. We also keep the reader open to ensure we don't miss the last lines in case of a log file rotation. Luckily a log file rotation always produces a create event, even on Windows. When this happens we reopen the path to get a handle to the new file. The code can be seen here: https://github.com/vanilla-technologies/minect/blob/d3c61efdeaa13e3c902f77747304547713c2bd5b/src/log/observer.rs#L127-L155

Comment: @Adrodoc thank you for following up with me on this

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a libaray may meet your request:
https://crates.io/crates/notify
But I'm not sure is it async.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to be a solution for windows. It seems like I edited my question while you were reading it, sorry :)